# SQL no such column error when it does exist

Tags: android, android-sqlite

When I query my database I keep getting an error saying `SQLException: no such column` and i do not understand why when my query looks just fine

```
Cursor nameCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(StatusList.STATUS_URI,new String[] {StatusList.STATUS_NAME,StatusList.STATUS_PERMISSIONS,StatusList.STATUS_ECM2ID}
                ,StatusList.STATUS_TYPE+"=1"+" AND "+StatusList.STATUS_NAME+"="+incidentCursor.getString(0),null,null);
```

here is the full error

```
08-01 15:39:59.104: W/System.err(8623): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: SIS (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT name, permissions, ecm2id FROM Status WHERE (type=1 AND name=SIS)
08-01 15:39:59.112: W/System.err(8623):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
08-01 15:39:59.112: W/System.err(8623):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
08-01 15:39:59.120: W/System.err(8623):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
08-01 15:39:59.120: W/System.err(8623):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
08-01 15:39:59.120: W/System.err(8623):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
08-01 15:39:59.120: W/System.err(8623):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
08-01 15:39:59.120: W/System.err(8623):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
08-01 15:39:59.120: W/System.err(8623):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
08-01 15:39:59.128: W/System.err(8623):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:400)
08-01 15:39:59.128: W/System.err(8623):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:294)
08-01 15:39:59.128: W/System.err(8623):     at ecm2.android.Providers.StatusList.query(StatusList.java:132)
08-01 15:39:59.128: W/System.err(8623):     at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:652)
08-01 15:39:59.128: W/System.err(8623):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:189)
08-01 15:39:59.128: W/System.err(8623):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:370)
08-01 15:39:59.135: W/System.err(8623):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:313)
08-01 15:39:59.135: W/System.err(8623):     at ecm2.android.MainActivity.createNewDialog(MainActivity.java:1167)
08-01 15:39:59.135: W/System.err(8623):     at ecm2.android.MainActivity$ListViews.onListItemClick(MainActivity.java:641)
08-01 15:39:59.135: W/System.err(8623):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
08-01 15:39:59.135: W/System.err(8623):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
08-01 15:39:59.135: W/System.err(8623):     at  android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)
08-01 15:39:59.143: W/System.err(8623):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2855)
08-01 15:39:59.143: W/System.err(8623):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3529)
08-01 15:39:59.143: W/System.err(8623):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-01 15:39:59.143: W/System.err(8623):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-01 15:39:59.143: W/System.err(8623):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-01 15:39:59.143: W/System.err(8623):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-01 15:39:59.143: W/System.err(8623):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 15:39:59.151: W/System.err(8623):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 15:39:59.151: W/System.err(8623):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-01 15:39:59.151: W/System.err(8623):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-01 15:39:59.151: W/System.err(8623):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Basically what I am trying to do it query my database for anything of `type 1` and a `name`

I know for a fact such record exists so I dont know why I am getting this error

EDIT:
Database creation code

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        createTables(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
                          int newVersion) 
    {
        Log.w("Messages", "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
              + " to "
              + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Incidents");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Distributions");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    private void createTables(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + INCIDENTS_TABLE + "(" + INCIDENT_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                INCIDENT_ECM2ID + " INTEGER, " + INCIDENT_STATON_NAME + " TEXT, " + INCIDENT_READ + " INTEGER, " + INCIDENT_TOC + " TEXT, " +
                INCIDENT_STATION_ID + " INTEGER, " + INCIDENT_MESSAGE_ID + " INTEGER, " + INCIDENT_MESSAGE + " TEXT);");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DISTRIBUTION_MESSAGES_TABLE + "(" + DIST_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                DIST_MESSAGE_ID + " INTEGER, " + DIST_ECM2ID + " INTEGER, " + DIST_SENDER_EMAIL + " TEXT, " + 
                DIST_SENDER_NAME + " TEXT, " + DIST_STATION_ID + " INTEGER, " + DISC_READ + " INTEGER, " + DIST_TOC + " TEXT, "
                + DIST_SUBJECT +" TEXT, " + DIST_MESSAGE + " TEXT);");
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to post the code where you create your database. Fresh eyes on existing code might help

Comment: edited with database creation code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SIS` is not a column, it should be a string. Either use the `?` substitution character or wrap your string in quotes.

Using SQL injection safe `?`:

```
Cursor nameCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(StatusList.STATUS_URI,
        new String[] {StatusList.STATUS_NAME, StatusList.STATUS_PERMISSIONS, StatusList.STATUS_ECM2ID},
        StatusList.STATUS_TYPE + "=1 AND " + StatusList.STATUS_NAME + "=?",
        new String[] {incidentCursor.getString(0)},
        null);
```

Using quotes:

```
Cursor nameCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(StatusList.STATUS_URI,
        new String[] {StatusList.STATUS_NAME, StatusList.STATUS_PERMISSIONS, StatusList.STATUS_ECM2ID},
        StatusList.STATUS_TYPE + "=1 AND " + StatusList.STATUS_NAME + "='" + incidentCursor.getString(0) + "'",
        null,
        null);
```

Comment: the quotes did it thanks! I just assumed since I was getting a string from the cursor it would be ok

Comment: @tyczj, never insert quote marks manually. Always use `?` and followed `selectionArgs` parameter. Imagin, your string will already contain single or double quote mark… BOOM!

Comment: @StenaviN Using quotes is safe if the user cannot interact with the data. There is no sense in preventing a SQL insertion attack from yourself.

Comment: @Sam, as you can see *tyczj* uses data from database to make another query and you can not rely on data safety because we don't know how data came to database. It is why I said that using query parameters is much safer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a correct way to build query:

```
Cursor nameCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
        StatusList.STATUS_URI,
        new String[] { StatusList.STATUS_NAME, StatusList.STATUS_PERMISSIONS, StatusList.STATUS_ECM2ID },
        StatusList.STATUS_TYPE + "=?" + " AND " + StatusList.STATUS_NAME + "=?",
        new String[] { "1", incidentCursor.getString(0) },
        null);
```