# Error: No such column name

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have been trying to execute a query:-

```
String selectQuery="SELECT "+ROLE+" FROM "+TABLE_EMPLOYEE+ " WHERE "+USER_ID+ "='"+userId+"' AND "+PASSWORD+"='"+password+"';";
cursorObj = dbObj.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

This will result to:-

```
SELECT Role FROM employee WHERE User_Id='HondaSE' AND Password='456';
```

The logcat says:-

```
01-08 12:05:10.070: W/System.err(9318): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column:
 HondaQE: , while compiling: SELECT Role FROM employee WHERE User_Id=HondaQE AND Password=123;
```

I have tried to run the query with double quotes as well, for userId and password. resulting in:-

```
SELECT Role FROM employee WHERE User_Id="HondaSE" AND Password="456";
```

However both the queryies work perfectly fine when executed in SQLITE Data browser.
Both respond with same error.

Comment: You are saying, the strings are having quotes around them  but as per logcat error, query is not having single quotes around Strings. So you must double check that. It must be some other query than one you mentioned in question

Comment: Nope, its the same query. I dont know wht log cat is not showing the quotes. as soon as the error was generated, i copied it from the logcat and pasted it here.

Comment: Try to do one thing. Put a debugging point when your query string is being generated. Check for quotes there

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite like this

```
String selectQuery="SELECT "+ROLE+" FROM TABLE_EMPLOYEE " WHERE USER_ID ='" + userId + "' AND PASSWORD = '" +password+ "'";
```

Comment: Hmm.. hard coding the column values?.. I tried, it still has the same error

Comment: Assuming USER_ID and PASSWORD as fields and userId and password are variables holding values. the query above should work. Please check database table for the columns(fields) USER_ID and PASSWORD

Comment: Yeah theu have the same column names as the variables hold. This same query when fired in the SQLite Data Browser works. So I feel there is nothing wrong with the query as such.

Comment: Check out this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766589/sql-no-such-column-error-when-it-does-exist?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Your logcat shows as below.

```
while compiling: SELECT Role FROM employee WHERE User_Id=HondaQE AND Password=123;
```

there is no single quotes around strings in `User_Id=HondaQE AND Password=123`.

Comment: But, as you can see the selectQuery has the quotes included. What can I do?

Comment: can you update your question with structure of `employee` table ? (columns in this table)

Comment: `String CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE + "("
     + USER_ID + " TEXT," + PASSWORD + " TEXT," + ROLE + " TEXT);";
     db.execSQL(CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TABLE);`

Comment: `//Employee Table 
public static final String TABLE_EMPLOYEE = "employee"; 

//Employee table columns names 
public static final String USER_ID = "User_Id"; 
public static final String PASSWORD = "Password"; 
public static final String ROLE = "Role";`

Comment: According to data you have provided, there are no any errors in query that you have executed and columns in table. clean and build your project and try to run.

Comment: Yes, I did all of that. All the other queries are working. A couple of select queries I have added in my project from a few days have stopped to work.

Answer (score 0):

You weren't compiling your raw query correctly. I would advise you to use "query" instead and use selection args to avoid these mistakes and possible sql injections.

Comment: `cursorObj = dbObj.query(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, new String[] {ROLE}, USER_ID +"="+userId+" AND "+ PASSWORD + "="+password, null, null, null, null);` 

The bove query resulted in the same message in the logcat

Answer (score 0):

I had the closed the db before accessing the cursor. This was the error.
After accessing the cursor, the db is to be closed. Error solved.